# Parse error with nvm.sh (node version manager)

Tags: node.js

OSX 10.7.3

When I try to run the Node Version Manager shell file I get the following error.

```
nvm.sh:73: parse error near `in^M'
```

there is nothing wrong with the file. no hidden characters etc.

I'm using oh-my-zsh as well but that should make any differnce. I have the same setup on my macbook and it works fine.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure your nvm.sh isn't in DOS format?

See whether `cat -v nvm.sh` shows `^M` characters at the end of lines?

EDIT:

To get rid of the `^M` characters you can use `dos2unix` or `tr`

```
dos2unix nvm.sh

tr -d '\r' < nvm.sh > nvm.sh.new
```

Comment: WOW. It's full of them. Every carriage return has them. How do I get rid of them?